# converting column from a factor to date format YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.SSSZ

Tags: r, data-formats

i want to convert the whole column from a factor to date.

The `str` of the dataset I am using is given below:

```
> str(dataset)
'data.frame':   2538 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ X        : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ SessionID: int  13307 21076 27813 8398 23118 12256 28799 11457 7542 19261 ...
 $ Timestamp: Factor w/ 2532 levels "2014-04-01T03:02:33.088Z",..: 2064 905 1086 1027 2419 1327 2035 1206 481 1354 ...
 $ ItemID   : int  214684513 214718203 214716928 214826900 214838180 214717318 214821307 214537967 214835775 214706432 ...
 $ Price    : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

How  can I convert timestamp variable from factor to specific date format:

> YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.SSSZ (2014-04-06T18:42:05.823Z)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to use the *PIPE* operator to pass the column of the dataframe into your function, then assign it back to the dataframe.

I created a dataframe with one column holding your example date string five times:

```
> x <- "2014-04-06T18:42:05.823Z"
> DF <- as.data.frame(c(x, x, x, x, x), colnames="original")
> colnames(DF) <- "original"
> str(DF)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ original: chr  "2014-04-06T18:42:05.823Z" "2014-04-06T18:42:05.823Z"
```

I use this *PIPE* symbol, which allows you to chain methods together, passing the output from one into the input of the following. Using a `.` symbolises the output from the previous method.

To make the *PIPE* operator available, load in the `magrittr` package (I believe it is also included in the *tidyverse*, so perhaps via the `dplyr` package:

```
library(maggritr)
```

Now I apply the `as.POSIXct` function to the `original` column, and save it back to the dataframe in a columnn called `new`:

```
DF$new <- DF$original %>% as.POSIXct(., tz = "UTC", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS")
> DF
                  original                     new
1 2014-04-06T18:42:05.823Z 2014-04-06 18:42:05.822
2 2014-04-06T18:42:05.823Z 2014-04-06 18:42:05.822
3 2014-04-06T18:42:05.823Z 2014-04-06 18:42:05.822
4 2014-04-06T18:42:05.823Z 2014-04-06 18:42:05.822
5 2014-04-06T18:42:05.823Z 2014-04-06 18:42:05.822

> str(DF)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ original: chr  "2014-04-06T18:42:05.823Z" "2014-04-06T18:42:05.823Z" ...
 $ new     : POSIXct, format: "2014-04-06 18:42:05.822" "2014-04-06 18:42:05.822" ...
```

You can remove the `original` column if you like, using:

```
df$original <- NULL
```

Comment: after applying this code when i display str(df) the got same result Timestamp with factor :(                                                                                                                   str(df)
'data.frame':   2538 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ X        : int  1 2 3 4 5  ...
 $ SessionID: int  13307 21076 27813 8398 23118 ...
 $ Timestamp: Factor w/ 2532 levels "2014-04-01T03:02:33.088Z",..: 2064 905 1086 1027 2419 1327 2035 1206 481 1354 ...
 $ ItemID   : int  214684513 214718203 214716928 214717318 214821307 214537967 214835775  ...
 $ Price    : int  0 0 0 0 0 0  ...

Comment: i want output like this     > str(dataset)
    'data.frame':   2538 obs. of  5 variables:
     $ X        : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
     $ SessionID: int  13307 21076 27813 8398 23118 12256 28799 11457 7542 19261 ...
     $ Timestamp: Date "2014-04-01T03:02:33.088Z",..: 2064 905 1086 1027 2419 1327 2035 1206 481 1354 ...
     $ ItemID   : int  214684513 214718203 214716928 214826900 214838180 214717318 214821307 214537967 214835775 214706432 ...
     $ Price    : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...

Comment: If you try my example with my data, do you get the same output I posted? Otherwise it might be useful to know how you are reading your data and creating the dataframe. Additionally, you could try first converting the `factor` column to a string column, so it matches my dataframe.